# Is there a preferred way of naming instance variables in Cocoa subclasses?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

When subclassing a class like MKMapView, is there a preferred way of naming the newly added instance variables? Apple says it reserves the underscore prefix for their own use, so can I just go ahead and use whatever I like without worrying about possible clashes?

Comment: I heard they prefer "Bob" over "Robert." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a name not used by any of your superclasses — the compiler will error out if you accidentally do and you'll just have to change the variable's name. In general, it's not a very big deal and you can use pretty much whatever you want. It's my observation that category methods are more prone to naming conflict problems than instance variables are.

Answer (score 1):

To be clearer; Apple reserve the underscore prefix for *method names* not *iVars*.

Many developers prefer to name their iVars with an underscore prefix to distinguish them from their property names.

Answer (score 1):

There's an entire [Apple programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) dedicated to naming conventions and style in Cocoa.

Comment: I've read it through, but section on ivars is very short and doesn't address this very specific problem

Answer (score 0):

Since your subclass will tend to have your own prefix (like EHMapView) you may prefix instance variables with `_eh_` (e.g. `_eh_foo`).

Comment: This actually conflicts with Apple's claim on the underscore prefix.

Comment: I still use the _ prefix for an easy distinction between private variables and public properties. From what I've read on the matter the bigger problem is prefixing private (category) methods.